# Logic (philosophy)

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, philosophy

Let P(x), Q(x), and R(x) be open sentences containing the variable x. Prove that if the statements for all x (P(x) implies Q(x)) and for at least x (∃x) (Q(x) implies R(x)) are true, then for all x (P(x) implies R(x)) is true. How can I do this without using truth tables?

Comment: you'll have a hard time proving that, because it doesn't follow from your premises. perhaps you meant the second premise to be universally quantified, not existentially quantified.

Comment: all quantiers Domains same.

Comment: You can't do it, with that second premise. I doubt the "$\exists x$", because what's inside it is a conditional. If it were "$\forall x$" then the whole thing would be straight out of Aristotle.

Comment: i add the original question thx

Answer (score 2):

Please notice two differences between what you have written here and the question:

The question says $R(y)$, not $R(x)$.

And also, it has $(\exists x(Q(x)) \implies R(y)$, not $\exists x (Q(x) \implies R(y))$.

You can translate into "natural deduction" (which is a lousy name, because it's a very artificial way of thinking), but the reason is this:

For any $x$, either $P(x)$ is true, in which case $Q(x)$ is true, and therefore $\exists x Q(x)$ is true, so $R(y)$ is true, and therefore $P(x) \implies R(y)$ is true, or $P(x)$ is false, so $P(x) \implies R(y)$ is true. In either case $R(y)$ is true. So $\forall x(P(x) \implies R(y))$ is true.

Comment: To me, working in a natural deduction system feels _a lot more natural_ than working in a Hilbert-style system or a symmetric sequent calculus. Before you start calling it "lousy", perhaps you ought to disclose which kind of formal system you champion instead ...

Comment: I don't champion any formal system. It is the entire concept of formalism that I find an artificial way of thinking. Don't get that wrong - I don't have a problem with formalism. I just don't find it to be a natural way of thinking. (I do a lot of programming, and that is not a natural way of thinking either!) And it is the *name* I said was lousy, not the system.